# BookshelfJS not returning null when relation not found

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm trying to fetch a relation on my model, filtering the relation query as seen below.  However, when the `WHERE` condition is not satisfied, instead of `galleries.pop().related('owner')` being null or undefined, it is an empty model.  Subsequently calling `.toJSON` on galleries sets `gallery.owner` to `{}`

```
Gallery
    .query(qb => {
        qb.select(Gallery.FILTERS.PUBLIC);
        if(last) {
            qb.where(sortBy, direction === 'desc' ? '<' : '>', last);
        }
        qb.orderBy(sortBy, direction);
        qb.limit(limit);
    })
    .fetchAll({
        withRelated:  {
            owner: qb => {
                qb.select(User.FILTERS.PREVIEW)
                qb.where('active','=','TRUE')
            }
        }
    })
    .then(g => console.log(g.toJSON()))
    .catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Maybe  you should create an issue on bookshelf's github repositery

Comment: done. https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/1299